# Trying to make a to do list

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript and coding in general, I'm  trying to make a simple to do list but cant get the delete button to delete all the checkboxes, it will only delete the last checkbox made. Thanks guys

http://jsfiddle.net/2L8y73ac/

```
var task = document.getElementById('textinput'); 

function ObjectTask() {
        self = this;
        self.init = function() {
            self.itemText=document.createTextNode(task.value);
            self.checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            self.checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            self.checkbox.name = task.value;
            self.checkbox.id = "checkbox";
            self.checkbox.value = "0";
            self.checkbox.onclick = self.clickMe;

            self.listItem=document.createElement("li");
            self.listItem.id = task.value;
            self.listItem.appendChild(self.itemText);
            self.listItem.appendChild(self.checkbox);

            self.deleteCheckBox = document.getElementById('deleteBtn');
            self.deleteCheckBox.onclick = self.deleteMe;
            document.getElementById('place').appendChild(self.listItem);
        }

        self.clickMe = function() {
            if (self.checkbox.value === "0") {
                self.checkbox.value = "1";
                console.log("1");
            }else {
                self.checkbox.value = "0";
                console.log("0");
            }
        } 

        self.deleteMe = function(){
            if (self.checkbox.value == "1"){ 
                var parent = self.listItem.parentNode;
                parent.removeChild(self.listItem);
          }
}

}

function taskadd() { 
    var taskNew = new ObjectTask();
    taskNew.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to get the adding to work either, but that doesn't matter. :)

The problem is that you assign a new click handler to the single delete button everytime when you add an item. When you click the delete button, the event handler of the last item is called, everytime (even when the item itself is already deleted).

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
self.deleteCheckBox = document.getElementById('deleteBtn');
self.deleteCheckBox.onclick = self.deleteMe;
```

`deleteCheckBox` is assigned the (global) delete button. After that, you assign a new onclick handler to it, overwriting the previous one.

A better approach would be to write one generic handler for the delete button, which looks up all selected checkboxes and finds the other elements belonging to it to delete them. So just like your global `taskadd()`, you should also have a global `taskdelete()` that deletes all selected tasks.

Comment: Awesome man thanks. I tried that before but I keep on gettting errors to. Here the js to my previous version.  http://jsfiddle.net/fbct3oL7/1/